# SQL Server check for data being updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hey all i have an app that runs everyday to gather updates for a table in my SQL Server 2008 database. I also have a front end website that displays those stats for a user.

I am trying to figure out away to inform the user, once they log into the website, that the db is currently being updated.

The code I have so far is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dataLog 
WHERE theDT >= '2012-12-05 00:00:00' 
  AND theDT <= '2012-12-05 23:59:59' 
  AND theType <> 'Completed'
```

When the app starts it writes this record to the `dataLog` table:

```
 id   | theDT                    | theMsg      | theFunction     | theType
 130    2012-12-05 09:17:13.000    Beginning     Main              Starting
```

And when its finished it writes:

```
 id   | theDT                    | theMsg      | theFunction     | theType
 137    2012-12-05 09:47:13.000    Ended         Main              Completed
```

I'm just not sure how to go about checking that as my code above shows it every time regardless if it has *completed* or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select max_dt, theType from
datalog d inner join
(SELECT max(theDt) as max_dt FROM dataLog) m
on d.theDt = m.max_dt
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks, Beth.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is too simple.

```
Select Top 1
  *
From dataLog
Where theDate < GetDate()
Order By theDate DESC
```

Then your front end can display the current status and, if the status is Starting, display the "Updating: started at x" message, and if status is "Completed", display the "Update completed at x" message.